# What rule of law requires gyms to release members from long term contracts when they relocate out of the area?

Tags: england-and-wales, consumer-protection, unfair-terms

In OFT v. Ashbourne Management Services Ltd, the high court apparently ordered gyms to relinquish members from ongoing liability after their life circumstances change such as an injury or a relocation to a different area so that it is impractical for them to continue utilising that fitness club.

What provision or rule of law was this order based on?

Comment: Have you read the decision?

Answer (score 2):

It's not specifically about injury or relocation but more generally about early termination of a contract and it depends on the wording in the 'version' of the contract.

[Gov.uk Ashbourne Management Services: unfair gym membership contracts](https://www.gov.uk/cma-cases/ashbourne-management-services-unfair-gym-membership-contracts):

> ... The Court held:
>
> - various terms of Ashbourne's standard form agreements are unfair    contrary to the Unfair Terms in Consumer Contracts Regulations 1999.
>   In particular:
>
>   - Terms in contracts 1 to 10 which required consumers to pay in full    for the remainder of the minimum membership period if they
>     wished to    cancel during this period. This was both because the
>     minimum term    operated as a "trap" for consumers who overestimate
>     the use they are    likely to make of the gym, and also because the
>     contracts unfairly    gave Ashbourne the right to demand too much in
>     payment;
>   - Terms in contracts 11 to 13 which tie consumers in for more than 12    months. The judge indicated that if there is a longer period it
>     would    be unfair unless the consumer could give 30 days notice to
>     cancel,    and pay a modest sum in compensation. The court was willing
>     to accept    a 12 month minimum period in contracts 11 to 13 because
>     they contain    more circumstances in which the consumer can suspend
>     or terminate    their membership for stated reasons. ...

[Unfair Terms in Consumer Contracts Regulations 1999](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/1999/2083)

The judgment on [Bailii - The Office of Fair Trading v Ashbourne Management Services Ltd & Ors [2011] EWHC 1237 (Ch) (27 May 2011)](https://www.bailii.org/ew/cases/EWHC/Ch/2011/1237.html)