# Does the provision sought by this question apply equally to coworking spaces?

Tags: contract-law, england-and-wales, consumer-protection, any-jurisdiction, unfair-terms

See this question: [What rule of law requires gyms to release members from long term contracts when they relocate out of the area?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/94708/what-rule-of-law-requires-gyms-to-release-members-from-long-term-contracts-when)

I intend to edit this question once that one is duly answered, but in the meantime, as a stand-in: is it fair and thus lawful for coworking memberships to bind their members to the full liability amount of a contract’s duration in case the member moves outside the service area of the coworking provider company?

Comment: It seems like these could be collapsed into a single question: "Does the law releasing gym members from their memberships due to a change in life circumstances in *OFT v. Ashbourne Management Services Ltd* impose the same requirements on coworking spaces?"

Comment: I’d hardly be opposed to that, and in fact rather agree; I’m only weary of users objecting to individual questions lacking “focus”

Answer (score 2):

### No

The key legislation in OFT v. Ashbourne Management Services Ltd was the Unfair Terms in Consumer Contracts Regulations 1999.

That law only applies to [consumers](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/450440/Unfair_Terms_Main_Guidance.pdf), an individual “acting wholly or mainly outside his or her business, trade, craft or profession.” While the law presumes an individual to be a consumer unless proven otherwise, it is difficult to see why a consumer (as defined) would need a coworking space. In addition, it is likely bordering on certain, that the coworking contract contained a warranty from the individual that they were “acting wholly or mainly” *inside* “his or her business, trade, craft or profession.”